# How to run background processes on Bluemix?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to get a really simple python program to run as a background process on IBM Bluemix as a CloudFoundry app.

I've put it in a [Github repo](https://github.com/Zapaan/bluemix-bg-proc-test).
There's a one-line req file because I find it easier than a setup.py and the python buildpack needs it to run.

My complete use-case is that I have an API written with Django and I need an MQTT client that will run besides it to collect data from a broker (something with Watson IOT I think).

I've tried to run both in the same CF app with a 2-lines Procfile looking like this :

```
web: gunicorn -e DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=conf.dev conf.wsgi --workers 2
worker: python time.py
```

but the second process was just ignored.

I've also tried in the current configuration, but with a Procfile containing only the second line and it was telling me that it couldn't find the start command.

Now, with start command in the Manifest and `no-route` at `true`, either it doesn't pass the health check, or it just wait at the starting step until I get this error :

```
2016-07-22T13:10:36.671+0200
[LGR/null]
err
WebsocketListener.Start: Error connecting to a doppler server
2016-07-22T13:10:36.677+0200
[LGR/null]
err
proxy: error connecting to 159.8.128.238:8081: dial tcp 159.8.128.238:8081: getsockopt: connection refused
```

So, is there a way to run background tasks in Bluemix, if possible as standalone app (to scale and update more easily) ?

EDIT : now it works, though I haven't changed anything besides a typo to format a string in my Python script, though the app crash just about every minute

```
Removing crash for app with id 3978a475-4dc6-495f-9662-a6fd562dc28a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer to the question : a separate app with the `no-route` argument set to `true`

Ok, so I've apparently got it to work fully.

I'm not sure what I've done but the problem might have come from the fact that I was asking for a 32M instance and the minimum seems to be 64M so Bluemix/CF wasn't so happy with my demand and crashed.

I was using 128M in my older tries but I think I didn't put `no-route: true` at the time

Comment: This is the correct way to do it, a separate app with no-route.

Comment: @opiethehokie exactly what I was trying to say

Answer (score 0):

I used the approach to run two separate apps for the web and the worker instances. However, I was still tripping over the health check which was failing.

So for the workers I reccomend disabling the routing and additionaly to disable health checks.

The following manifest worked for running Django through gunicorn for web and celery for the workers.

My `manifest.yml`

```
---
applications:
  - name: myapp
    host: myapp
    domain: eu-de.mybluemix.net
    memory: 128M
    command: bash ./run_web.sh

  - name: myapp-workers
    memory: 128M
    no-route: true
    health-check-type: none
    command: bash ./run_worker.sh
```

The `run_web.sh` and `run_worker.sh` shell scripts contain the commands to run the components, and for the web instance I added migration and collecstatic commands to the run script.